Why doesn't the in-place operation on leaf variables in PyTorch optimizers cause an error?
When I want to do in-place operation on leaf variable, I get an error:
import torch
x = torch.tensor([2.0, 10.0], requires_grad=True)

y = x[0]**2 + x[1]**2

y.backward()

x.add_(0.2, alpha=0.2) # RuntimeError: a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.

But we do not have this problem in optim.step() of the optimizer in the training loop. You know this method is operating on neural network parameters which are also leaf variable. I checked the step() function code and did not see with no_grad() statement, so I wonder why in-place operation in this method does not cause an error. Here is in-place operation in optimizer code: param.add_(grad, alpha=-lr). There was no detaching of the gradient in between.

tl;dr they are using no_grad, just in another location and in a slightly more complex way
In detail:
Walk up the stack. param.add_(grad, alpha=-lr) is a line in _single_tensor_sgd. _single_tensor_sgd is called by sgd. sgd is called by optim.SGD.step.
The step function has the _use_grad_for_differentiable decorator. This is the code for the decorator:
def _use_grad_for_differentiable(func):
    def _use_grad(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import torch._dynamo

        prev_grad = torch.is_grad_enabled()
        try:
            # documentation here omitted for brevity
            torch.set_grad_enabled(self.defaults["differentiable"])
            torch._dynamo.graph_break()
            ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            torch._dynamo.graph_break()
            torch.set_grad_enabled(prev_grad)
        return ret

    functools.update_wrapper(_use_grad, func)
    return _use_grad

All pytorch optimizers have a self.defaults attribute that holds several flags, including a differentiable flag. The _use_grad_for_differentiable decorator sets the grad status based on the self.defaults["differentiable"] flag of the optimizer.
This is done to allow for flexibility.
Most optimizers (ie the standard optimizers in Pytorch) have self.defaults["differentiable"]=False, so this decorator operates like no_grad. This is why the in-place operation in SGD doesn't throw an error.
The use of the differentiable flag allows people to experiment with differentiable optimizers in a way that would not be possible if they simply applied no_grad to the whole thing.
You can also test this. This code runs fine:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

x = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([2.0, 10.0]))

opt = torch.optim.SGD([x], 1e-3)

loss = x.sum()
loss.backward()

opt.step()

This code throws an error at the in-place operation:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

x = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([2.0, 10.0]))

opt = torch.optim.SGD([x], 1e-3)
opt.defaults['differentiable'] = True

loss = x.sum()
loss.backward()

opt.step()

